# TideSDK: Put all files into 1 *.exe and/or obfuscate the code

Tags: php, windows, exe, tidesdk, code-access-security

Has there been any movement of TideSDK adding capabilities to protect the source code of the applications we build using it. I have php files with database connection strings and I need to have my application launch on a public pc in an internet cafe so having my code just sitting there for an opportune hacker is not very optimal.

I would really like to stay with the TideSDK platform so Im not looking for an alternative, just a way to create a secure public application that protects my database as much as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tidekit does that for you : code obfuscation

You may need to wait until tidekit is released, plus TideSDK will not receive support anymore until TideKit is released.